# SQL query - not equal to

Tags: sql, oracle

Using the `books` table, write a query that will list all information about those books that are not computer books and do not cost more than $30.00 retail.

This is what I have:

```
select * from books where (category != 'computer') AND retail < 30.00;
```

But it keeps giving me `"computer"` in the category section.

Will greatly appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Please add some sample data and your expected result ;).

Comment: Is you Database case sensitive? I would copy the text from the result set and paste it in the place of Category filter.

Comment: Can you confirm that computer is computer and does not have any white spaces before or after it? What do you get for where category = 'computer'

Comment: add a length column `Len(category)` or appropriate for your RDBMS.  is it 8 for those with computer showing? perhaps you have a non-display ascii character in there or try `category not like %computer%` if it goes away.. you have a hidden character somewhere.

Comment: "computer" <> computer? ))

Comment: `select category, dump(category), dump('computer') from books`, compare the result byte-wise

Answer (score 0):

Your query runs just fine on MySql... what DBMS are you using, you tagged mysql *and* SQLServer...

```
 select * from books where (category != 'computer') AND retail < 30.00;
```

check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96614/1)

EDIT: So you are using sqlPlus... I'cant find a fiddle for that, I would try to use just:

```
 select * from books where category <> 'computer' AND retail < 30.00;
```

If sqlPlus is for Oracle 11g R2, check [this other fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/746542/1), it seems your query works as expected.

Comment: Sorry about that I am using sqlPlus

Comment: SQL*Plus is the command line for Oracle. You surmised correctly.

Comment: I'm just thinking maybe `"computer"` is the value of the category column and not `computer`... anyway tell us what was the problem when you solve this puzzle :)

Answer (score 0):

Is you Database case sensitive? I would copy the text from the result set and paste it in the place of Category filter. Try something like this. The code is in T-SQL, please adapt as needed

```
SELECT * from books 
WHERE UPPER(RTRIM(category)) != N'COMPUTER'
AND retail < 30.00;
```

Worth Checking how many categories you have if the above does not work. Will give you some clues.

```
SELECT DISTINCT category
FROM books 
ORDER BY category
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `<>` instead of `!=`
If you're database is case sensitive then you will need a condition for each of the permutations, which you can use the `NOT IN ('Computer','computer')` operation.

Comment: It is definitely not case sensitive and I tried <> instead of != but it's still giving me the same answer.

Comment: You could try the not in operation with just the one value. It won't be very efficient.

Comment: Is the column a variable length or a fixed length?  That will make a difference if you need to trim the end to get rid of the padded spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE ( category != 'computer' AND retail < 30 )
```

In Open Office Base, I needed to use NOT IN as suggested by @Aaron.

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE ( category NOT IN ('computer', 'Computer') AND retail < 30 )
```